# Transforming xml to xml using xslt encoded hierarchy problem xslt v1

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

In my input xml file I have got encoded hierarchy in elements attribute "lp":

```
<element lp="1"/>
<element lp="1.1"/>
<element lp="2"/>
<element lp="3"/>
<element lp="3.1" />
<element lp="3.2" />
<element lp="3.2.1" />
```

How to transform this xml data to

```
<element lp="1">
   <element lp="1.1"/>
</element>
<element lp="2"/>
<element lp="3">
   <element lp="3.1"/>
   <element lp="3.2">
      <element lp="3.2.1">
   </element>
</element>
```

Comment: Your input XML only has certain @lp attributes ending in a full stop (ie. lp="1.", lp="2.", lp="3."), but in your output XML, all @lp attributes end in a full-stop with the exception lp="3.2.1". Is this intentional?

Comment: sorry there is no dots at the end of attribute "lp" value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is probably a simply way to do this with XSLT2.0, but I have assumed XSLT1.0 here.

One thing to not is that your XML is not strictly valid, because it lacks a root element. For the purposes of the answer, I have assumed the root element is called **elements**

To achieve this, I think you need a function to determine the 'level' of an element. This can be done by counting the number of full stops in the @lp attribute. In XSLT1.0 I have done this by removing all full-stops from the text, and comparing the resultant string length with the original string length

```
<xsl:variable name="level" select="string-length(@lp) - string-length(translate(@lp, '.', ''))" />
```

Thus to match the top level elements you would do this...

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
   select="element[string-length(@lp) - string-length(translate(@lp, '.', '')) = 0]"/>
```

This would match the folllowing elements

```
<element lp="1."/>
<element lp="2."/>
<element lp="3."/>
```

Next, for each matched element, it is a case of matching following elements where

- The @lp attribute begins with the current @lp attribute
- The level is one more than the current level

This can be done with the following select

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
   select="following-sibling::element[substring(@lp, 1, $len) = $lp][string-length(@lp) - string-length(translate(@lp, '.', '')) = $level + 1]"/>
```

(Note $len and $level are variables containing the length of the current @lp attribute and the current level)

Putting this altogether gives the following XSLT....

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:template match="/elements">
      <elements>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="element[string-length(@lp) - string-length(translate(@lp, '.', '')) = 0]"/>
      </elements>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="element">
      <xsl:variable name="lp" select="@lp"/>
      <xsl:variable name="len" select="string-length(@lp)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="level" select="$len - string-length(translate(@lp, '.', ''))" />

      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:copy-of select="@lp"/>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::element[substring(@lp, 1, $len) = $lp][string-length(@lp) - string-length(translate(@lp, '.', '')) = $level + 1]"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following XML

```
<elements>
    <element lp="1"/>
    <element lp="1.1"/>
    <element lp="2"/>
    <element lp="3"/>
    <element lp="3.1"/>
    <element lp="3.2"/>
    <element lp="3.2.1"/>
</elements>
```

Produces the following output

```
<elements>
    <element lp="1">
        <element lp="1.1"/>
    </element>
    <element lp="2"/>
    <element lp="3">
        <element lp="3.1"/>
        <element lp="3.2">
            <element lp="3.2.1"/>
        </element>
    </element>
</elements>
```

Comment: +1 good answer. FYI, his input XML is not strictly *well-formed*. The term "valid" does not apply here (positively or negatively) because there is no schema (DTD etc.) for the document to be validated against.

Comment: thank you for correct answer. I ignored document validation context in question because I want to focus only on the algorithmic problem

Answer (score 3):

I think this was answer before... This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <result>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="element[not(contains(@lp,'.'))]"/>
        </result>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="element">
    <xsl:variable name="vLevel" select="concat(@lp,'.')"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates
                 select="../element[starts-with(@lp,$vLevel)]
                                   [not(contains(substring-after(@lp,$vLevel),
                                                 '.'))]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<result>
    <element lp="1">
        <element lp="1.1"></element>
    </element>
    <element lp="2"></element>
    <element lp="3">
        <element lp="3.1"></element>
        <element lp="3.2">
            <element lp="3.2.1"></element>
        </element>
    </element>
</result>
```